# 2-dimensional Array - unset if not value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unset

I have a 2-dimensional array and want to delete all elements, whose values are not "Name1". They should keep their index numbers (keys):

```
Array
(
    [array001] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Name2
            [2] => Name3
            [3] => Name1
        )

    [array002] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => Name1
            [2] => Name4
        )
    [array003] => Array
    ....
)
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [array001] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [3] => Name1
        )

    [array002] => Array
        (
            [1] => Name1
        )
    [array003] => Array
    ....
)
```

Possible solutions could be achieved with a foreach loop, with preg_replace, when the array is converted into a string: `$array = print_r($array,true);`

Answer (score 1):

none of them is working..

I found the solution by myself:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  foreach($value as $innerkey => $innervalue){
    if($innervalue != 'Name1'){
      unset($array[$key][$innerkey]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $string) {

        if ($string !== "Name1") {
            unset($string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function removeElementDifferentValue($array, $value){
     foreach($array as $subKey => $val){
          if($val != $value){
               unset($array[$subKey]);
          }
     }
     return $array;
}

$array = removeElementWithValue($array, 'Name1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key1 => $val1) {
    foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2) {
        if(strcmp($val2,"Name1") != 0) {
            unset($array[$key1][$key2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not working, see my solution I found myself ;)
`Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets`

Comment: Your code is the same as mine, you just use a different string comparison.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, I don't know what caused the error ;)
Thanks anyway!